# Module Theory: about the genesis of the concept

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I'm studying the module theory. But, I really want to know the history of the genesis of the concept of R-module.

On my years as a student, my Algebra teacher presenteed to me the concept as a simple generalization of the F-vector space concept . But now I have doubts about this because on the book of Enzo Gentile (Estructuras Algebraicas II) and, in many others books, I found that the notion of R-module arises from the Representation of rigns.

So,

1.- What is the real origin of the module theory?

2.- Any suggestion for a textbook to study the representations of rings via modules?

3.- Why we should study the Rrepresentation Theory of rings?

Comment: The 1st question is a history question. The 2nd question is a shopping question. The 3rd is way too broad. I'd like to see an answer to the 1st question, though the other two are not appropriate for this site.

Comment: You might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/142047/242) of interest.

Comment: There is a nice book called [pioneers of representation theory](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=HMATH-15-S) which addresses  most of your questions, and this is a [review](http://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/reviews/pdf/curtis.pdf) of the mensioned book.

Comment: Thank you for everbody. I apreciate your help and I apologize for not say before.